# Converting list returned through LINQ to list of class objects

Tags: c#, linq

I got a list using LINQ-to-SQL:

```
var query = studentRankTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r =>
        new
        {
            Name = r.Field<string>("ID"),
            Action = r.Field<string>("Name")
        })
    .Select(grp =>
        new
        {
            Name = grp.Key.Name,
            Action = grp.Key.Action,
            Count = grp.Count()
        });

query = query.ToList();
```

The end value of the `query` is:

```
[0] { Name = "831001", Action = "Login", Count = 8 }    <Anonymous Type>
[1] { Name = "810030", Action = "Game Map Visit", Count = 4 }   <Anonymous Type>
```

Now I have to convert this into a class that I have defined:

```
[DataContract]
public class StudentRank
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to use `foreach` because it has datatype of anonymous

How can I convert this list to a list of `StudentRank` objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use the `StudentRank` class in `Select` clause of LINQ:

```
var query = studentRankTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r =>
        new
        {
            Name = r.Field<string>("ID"),
            Action = r.Field<string>("Name")
        })
    .Select(grp =>
        new StudentRank 
        {
            Name = grp.Key.Name,
            Action = grp.Key.Action,
            Count = grp.Count()
        });
```

This way return type of this query will be `IQueryable<StudentRank>` so `ToList()` will return `List<StudentRank>` which can be easily used.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually nothing stopping you from using foreach if you use a [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) iterator

```
foreach(var s in result)
{
     ...
}
```

This auto-types `s` and works even for anonymous types

Also, Select would work here

```
query = query.Select(s => new Student { Name = s.Name, Action = s.Action, Count = s.Count });
```

Finally, if you pull into an actual list, there is the [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one in your `select`:

```
Select(grp => new StudentRank
              {
                  Name = grp.Key.Name,
                  Action = grp.Key.Action,
                  Count = grp.Count()
              });
```

This way instead of creating an object of anonymous type foreach item in your sequence, you create an object of type `StudentRank` foreach item in your sequence.

Furthermore, If you want only to iterate through the elements of your query's result, you don't have to call the `ToList()`.

You could achieve that you want as easy as the following:

```
foreach(var item in items)
```

where I have called the result of your query as `items`, in order to be more meaningfull.